# How to check in array how much times each word repeats itself and push it to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Lets say i have an array like this:

```
let votesArr = [yes,no,yes,no,yes];
```

and i want to to count how much times every word repeats itself and push to another so the output looks like this:

```
let votesData = [3,2]; // 3 for three yeses and 2 for two nos.
```

and i want to to work on many types of arrays like this, lets say an array that has 3 or 4 unique word.
I'm trying for a lot of time already and can't do that.

Comment: please add for other words some use cases with result and what you have tried.

Comment: That data structure is kind of poor... you have no indication of what the numbers in the second array are referring to... You should push objects instead: `let votesData = [{value: 'yes', count: 3},{value: 'no', count: 2}]`. Then loop while your array has a size, get the first instance, filter out all instances that match that, remove them from the array you are looping, and add the size to your votesData. Something along those lines?

Comment: @TylerDahle The data structure is like that because i'm using ChartJS and you can put the data only in arrays and not i arrays of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the power of [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
var array = ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes'],
    map = new Map,
    result;

array.forEach(v => map.set(v, (map.get(v) || 0) + 1));
result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just returning a plain array of counts will not make sense I guess. It should be more like below. If you don't want this output then just map the values to form an array.

```
{
  "yes": 3,
  "no": 2
}
```

```js
let votesArr = ["yes","no","yes","no","yes"];

const mappedArr = votesArr.reduce((a, b) => { 
  a[b] = a[b] || 0;
  a[b] += 1;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(mappedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
let votesArr = ["yes","no","yes","no","yes"];

let countSummary = votesArr.reduce( (count, val) => {
    if(!count[val]) { count[val] = 0 }
        count[val]++;
    return count;
}, {})
console.log(countSummary)// {yes: 3, no: 2}
let countSummmaryArr = Object.keys(countSummary).map(k=>countSummary[k]);

console.log(countSummmaryArr )// [3,2]
```

The way this works is that the `.reduce` counts every instance to a map of values, and the `.map` converts it to an array of the values.

Answer (score 0):

The below does what you need, although I'm sure it could be cleaned up a bit.

```
var data = ["Unsure", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Maybe", "Unsure"];
var counts = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    (counts[data[i]]) ? counts[data[i]]++ : counts[data[i]] = 1; 

}

// counts = {Unsure: 2, Yes: 3, No: 2, Maybe: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```js
let votesArr = ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes'];
// Create an empty object to store array item as key & its 
// number of repeat as value
var itemObj = {};
// loop over it and store the value in the object
var m = votesArr.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!itemObj[item]) {
    itemObj[item] = 1
  } else {
    itemObj[item] = itemObj[item] + 1
  }
});
// Use object.values to retrive the value
console.log(Object.values(itemObj))
```